# Manually correcting raster DEM (OpenSource)?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, dem, saga

Is it possible, to correct a raster DEM by changeing the raster-cell-values manually, like by "painting"?

My DEM (ASTER) have one small error where the elevation is about 300m below the actual elevation. It should be a hill, and not a hole...

SRTM 4.1 is good, but has other errors (the hill is very steep and small, so SRTM "ignores" it (<90m).

[image]

Comment: In this question, it looks like you are referring to the fact that there is a steep hill or spire, inside the circle of your 3125 contour, that is not shown on your DEM.  If this is the case, I would hesitate to call it an error.  If a feature is too small to be captured within the stated resolution of a dataset, it doesn't make the data wrong.  The DEM is correct based on the stated parameters of how it was created.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, in GRASS you can edit raster cells graphically with d.rast.edit.

[image: Raster cell editor in GRASS 7]

Answer (score 11):

I hesitate to mention this because markusN's answer is so good. But if you don't get on with GRASS and if your DEM is not too large you could try the following.

Firstly, note the coordinates for the pixels that you wish to edit. Then explode the DEM to xyz triplets using gdal2xyz:

gdal2xyz.py input_dem.tif output.csv

'output.csv' will be a space delimited text file containing the xyz triplets.

Next, load 'output.csv' into a plain text editor, search to find the coordinates and change their z-values as required. Save the file, then convert it to a DEM TIF using gdal_translate:

gdal_translate output.csv new_dem.tif

Nick.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, I stumbled upon it in search for the same thing. I later found that the [Serval](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Serval/) QGIS plugin does exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

There is another Qgis plugin designed for that: [ThRasE](https://github.com/SMByC/ThRasE)

> Disclosure: I developed this plugin, and I don't want to promote it, I just want to share another option

Comment: [**Avoid overt self-promotion.**  The community tends to vote down overt self-promotion and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).  In practice this means any answer that recommends your own product must include something like "**Disclosure:** I am the [position] of [company] that develops/distributes this software".

Comment: I think the idea of the ThRasE plugin is awesome and quite useful. However, the current version is a bit limited in the sense that it only applies to integer values, and it seems that in order to work, it requires that the raster has a very limited number of values. I tried to use it to modify a terrain file and it was really challenging to make it work.

Comment: Hi Juan, thanks for your comment, and yes ThRasE is a thematic editor tool and thematic means discrete values, and add the possibility to edit continuous values will be difficult to manage the table for editing the values, but any ideas or suggestions are welcome. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Raster calculator to change certain values on the raster. For example, if you want to transform all values between 300 and 310 to 305, raster calculator can do that. The [QGIS manual has some examples on this](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html). The last 5 minutes of this [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V8VUqUHCPcQ) also has an example on this.